# Every pull request merge increments behind commits to the main

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I'm beginner to Github. First I created an empty repository by creating a only a readme file. Then I cloned it to my computer and added some files and commited them to push. It push fine because that is main branch.

The problem is when creating a new branch based on ***main*** branch, let's take it as ***dev*** . After change some files, I pushed the commit and create the pull request. Until that, Github shows dev has 1 commit ahead ***main*** . After merging the pull request, it shows ***dev*** branch behind commits with *main* branch. Each time I try it increments the behind commits count.
***dev*** also not receiving updated commits done for ***main*** branch by other than *dev* to pull from origin.

I also tried creating new branch ***dev*** after cloning the repo and update initial changes through it other than using ***main*** branch. It gives the same result with behind commits. I want to know how to fix this to work properly.

Comment: Check your commit history for both branches. You probably pushed something to main that never got merged with dev at some point.

Comment: rebasing dev could solve your problem